# Polymer 1.0 : split index.html

Tags: polymer-1.0

I want to split my index.html file as it's too long(more than 500 lines) due to many submenus like the one below.

```
<paper-submenu>
<paper-item class="menu-trigger">
<iron-icon icon="add-circle-outline"></iron-icon>
<span>Medical</span>
</paper-item>
<paper-menu class="menu-content">
<a data-route="medical" href="/medical">
 <paper-item>
  <span>Introduction</span>
 </paper-item>
</a>
```

Is it possible to store all the submenu lines in the index.html into another file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom element?

Comment: @ChrisW How to put menus and submenus into a custom element? Is it possible? Any reference material is appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisW I made a custom element to store my submenus, and it works, but, font formats are all damaged. Maybe I need more CSS knowledge. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- Make sure to add other dependencies here -->

<dom-module id="test-comp">
  <template>
    <paper-submenu>
      <paper-item class="menu-trigger">
        <iron-icon icon="add-circle-outline"></iron-icon>
        <span>{{title}}</span>
      </paper-item>
      <paper-menu class="menu-content">
        <a data-route="{{dataRoute}}" href="{{href}}">
          <paper-item>
            <span>{{item}}</span>
          </paper-item>
        </a></paper-menu>
    </paper-submenu>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'test-comp',

        properties: {
          title: {},
          dataRoute: {},
          href: {},
          item: {},
        },


      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Now insert the element like so

`<test-comp title="Medical" data-route="medical" href="/medical" item="Introduction"></test-comp>`

Edit: The styles that affect your index.html will not affect your custom component. Add styles INSIDE your custom component to have them included